# Токен при авторизации

Tags: php, mysql, sql

При авторизации сохраняется в куки и бд случайно генерированый ключ (token). Я создаю чат. И я не знаю, как пользоваться токеном. Есть предположение, что, когда пользователь авторизуется, в бд вносится новый token. А дальше не понимаю, как им пользоваться. Или не стоит делать токен?

Comment: Токен (авторизации) https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Токен_(авторизации)

Comment: вы наверно меня не правильно поняли, токен, который генерируется и сохраняется в бд

Comment: Я ссылку дал для определения Вами, нужен ли он Вам - собственно, если реализовано и записывается - значит, используется  и нужно по нему определять пользователя. То есть, получается - наличие куки -> наличие токена и сопоставление с авторизованным пользователем.

Comment: А если пользователь зашел с 1 устройства и у него сгенерировался токен и сохранился в бд и в куки. После, он зашел с другого устройства, как поступить в этом случае, что бы и на 1 устройстве и на 2 устройстве работало?

Comment: Никак, без реализации внутреннего агрегатора авторизованных устройств

Comment: Что за агрегатор авторизованных устройств?

Comment: Сохраняете токен в куки или сессию. Соответственно на сервере читаете токен и если он валидный, обрабатываете свою логику. Для нескольких устройств можно генерировать разные токены или отдавать текущий, для устройств, которые передали верные логин и пароль.

Comment: В чем проблема при авторизации на другом устройстве, отдавать токен, так же как и в первый раз?

Comment: ArchDemon, а как это отметить в бд, что этот же человек, который зашел с разных устройств, это он?

Comment: А как Вы отмечаете сейчас, что "этому токену соответствует этот пользователь"?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос больше относится к области аутентификации пользователей. Обычно аутентификация пользователей строится поверх механизма управления сессиями. Она реализует т.н. *пользовательские сессии*, позволяющие определить при каждом запросе  от какого конкретного пользователя пришел запрос.

Практически все современные фреймворки предоставляют реализацию механизма аутентификации пользователей и управления сессиями пользователей на основе СУБД, это как раз то, о чем Вы спрашиваете. Но Вы, как я понял, хотите понимания на низком уровне взаимодействия, т.е. на *native PHP*.

Найти подходящий пример для Вас за вменяемое время не удалось, поэтому попробую создать пример самостоятельно. Не обессутьте - это *минималистичный учебный пример* для понимания сути, а не код для "боевого" применения. Безопасностью от SQL-инъекций я тоже не заморачивался. Написан для СУБД MySQL.

1. Нужна таблица с данными пользователей для их (пользователей) регистрации и последующей аутентификации. Для примера пусть будет

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`login`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

2. Нужна таблица для хранения сессий. Для простоты будем считать, что сессионные данные не хранятся, требуется *только аутентификация пользователя*.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `last_activity` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

3. Типовые операции:

```php
// время жизни сессии (30 дней) со времени последнего обращения пользователя
const SESSION_TTL = 2592000; // секунд

// коннект к СУБД
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $mysqlUser, $mysqlPass);

// ---------------
// регистрация нового пользователя c логином $userLogin и паролем $userPassword
$passHash = password_hash($userPassword,  PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$pdo->query(
    "INSERT INTO users (login, password) VALUES ('$userLogin', '$passHash')"
);

// ---------------
// Аутентфикация пользователя c логином $userLogin и паролем $userPassword
$result = $pdo->query(
    "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE login='$userLogin'"
);
if ($result) {
    // пользователь найден, проверяем пароль
    $userData = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result->closeCursor();
    if (!password_verify($userPassword, $userData['password'])) {
        // пароль не совпал, завершаем работу
        exit(1);
    }
    // пароль совпал, создаем новую сессию пользователя
    $userId = $userData['id'];
    $result = $pdo->query('SELECT UUID() AS session_id');
    $s = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result->closeCursor();
    $sessionId = $s['session_id'];
    $pdo->query(
        "INSERT INTO sessions (id, user_id)
                VALUES ('$sessionId', '$userId')"
    );
    // устанавливаем куку с идентификатором сессии
    setcookie('session_id', $sessionId, time() + SESSION_TTL, '/'); 
} else {
    // пользователь не найден, завершаем работу
    exit(1);
}

// ---------------
// проверка наличия легитимной сессии пользователя и его данных
if ($sid = $_COOKIE['session_id']) {
    $result = $pdo->query(
        "SELECT u.id, u.login
         FROM sessions AS s LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (s.user_id=u.id)
         WHERE s.id='$sid' AND
          last_activity>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SESSION_TTL . " SECOND)"
    );
    $userData = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result->closeCursor();
    if (!$userData) {
        // легитимная сессия пользователя не найдена, завершаем работу
        exit(1);
    }
    // обновляем время последнего обращения пользователя
    $pdo->query("UPDATE sessions SET last_activity=NOW() WHERE id='$sid'");
    // обновляем срок ханения сессионной куки
    setcookie('session_id', $sid, time() + SESSION_TTL, '/');
} else {
    // пользователь не аутентифицирован, завершаем работу
    exit(1);
}

// ---------------
// получить все активные сессии текущего пользователя по его $userId
$result = $pdo->query(
    "SELECT id
     FROM sessions
     WHERE user_id=$userId AND
           last_activity>=DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SESSION_TTL . " SECOND)"
);
$sessions = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $sessions[] = $row['id'];
}
$result->closeCursor();

// ---------------
// "разлогинить" пользователя текущей сессии - в 2 этапа
// 1. удаляем запись о сессии пользователя
$sid = $_COOKIE['session_id'];
$pdo->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id='$sid'");
// 2. удаляем сессионную куку.
setcookie('session_id', '', time() - SESSION_TTL, '/');

// ---------------
// удалить все неактивные (просроченные) сессии пользователей
$pdo->query(
    "DELETE FROM sessions
     WHERE last_activity<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SESSION_TTL . " SECOND)"
);
```

При любом обращении пользователя Вы в первую очередь проверяете его авторизацию через куку ("токен"). Если пользователь залогинен - все хорошо, обрабатываете его запрос. Если не залогинен (нет активной сессии с ID, указаной в сессионной куке, или нет самой сессионной куки) - отправляете его на страницу авторизации. Если нужно что-то отправить пользователю во все его сессии (одна сессия - с домашнего компа, вторая - с рабочего, третья - с телефона, и т.д.) - первым делом получаете все активные (не просроченные) сессии этого пользователя, чтобы знать куда слать.

Время от времени чистите таблицу сессий от просроченных сессий, чтобы не засорялась и быстрее работала.

Дополнительная информация:

- [Функции хеширования паролей](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.password.php)
- [Класс PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php)
- [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php)
- [MySQL UUID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)